# How to use grep and sed simultaneously using pipe

Tags: awk, sed, terminal, grep

I have 2 files

File 1

```
TRINITY_DN10039_c1_g1_i1        216     Brassica rapa   
TRINITY_DN10270_c0_g1_i1        233     Pan paniscus  
TRINITY_DN10323_c0_g1_i2        209     Corynebacterium aurimucosum ATCC 700975  
.  
.   
TRINITY_DN10462_c0_g1_i1        257     Helwingia himalaica    
TRINITY_DN10596_c0_g1_i1        205     Homo sapiens   
TRINITY_DN10673_c0_g2_i2        323     Anaerococcus prevotii DSM 20548
```

File 2

```
TRINITY_DN9856_c0_g1_i1 len=467 path=[0:0-466]
GATGCGGGCCAATATGAATGTGAGATTACTAATGAATTGGGGACTAAAAA
TRINITY_DN9842_c0_g1_i1 len=208 path=[0:0-207]
AAGTAATTTTATATCACTTGTTACATCGCAATTCGTGAGTTAAACTTAAT
.
.
TRINITY_DN9897_c0_g1_i1 len=407 path=[0:0-406]
AACTTTATTAACTTGTTGTACATATTTATTAATGCAAATACATATAGAG  
TRINITY_DN9803_c0_g1_i1 len=795 path=[0:0-794]
AACTAAGACAAACTTCGCGGAGCAGTTAGAAAATATTACAAGAGATTTG
```

I want to delete 2 lines(same line and next line) in file2 whose pattern matches with the first column words of 1st file

```
awk '{print $1}' file1 | sed '/here_i_want_to_insert_output_of_pipe/{N;d;}' file2
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, good that you have shown your attempted code. Please do wrap your samples in code tags as they are not clear.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I am a biologist, I don't know how to describe the problem properly, thank you

Comment: I haven't said about explanation, I only requested to wrap your samples with code tags.

Comment: Just wondering, are you not missing the `>` in front of `TRINITY`?

Comment: @kvantour I understand you are a biologist, I removed > symbol to make my question more general, so that i may get answer quickly

Comment: @Abhilash There are already many fasta-file questions here. The availability of the `>` sign, makes its processing easier. By removing the sign, you made the question more generic, but that also means that the complexity of the answer is higher. If you would add the sign, we can help you out with a well tuned answer that, after minor tweaking,  might be of assistance to you in other processing tasks. The answers now are actually less useful to you.

Comment: @kvantour Thank you, I am not aware that bioinformatics related queries can also be  asked here

Comment: @to_all_users who see this answer the file 2 is usually fasta file and file1 is contaminations.txt from NCBI. so just edit file1 by removing the header line and other text.

then use this command sed `"$(cut  -f1 file1 | sed 's@.*@/&/{N;d}@')"  file2 >> edited.fasta`

Reference:Kamilcuk answer

Thanks to KamilCuk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the field has no special characters in the first field, like `.` or `/` or `[` or `(` or `\` or any regex-special characters, your idea is actually not that bad:

```
sed "$(cut -d' ' -f1 file1 | sed 's@.*@/&/{N;d}@')" file2
```

- `cut -d' ' -f1 file1` - extract first field from file1
- `| sed`

  - `.*` - replace anything. ie. the first field from file1
  - `/&/{N;d}` - the `&` is substituted for the whole thing we are replacing. So for the first field. So it becomes `/<first field>/{N;d}`
- then wrap it around `sed "<here>" file2`

No so much known feature, you can use another character for `/regex/` with syntax `\<char>regex<char>` like `\!regex!`. Below I use `~`:

```
 sed "$(cut -d' ' -f1 file1 | sed 's@.*@\\~&~{N;d}@')" file2
```

If you however do have any special characters on the first field, then if you don't care about sorting: You can replace two lines in file2 for a single line with some magic separator (I chose `!` below), then sort it and sort file1, and then just `join` them. The `-v2` makes `join` output unpairable lines from second file - ie. not matched lines. After that restore the newline, by replacing the magic separator `!` for a newline:

```
join -v2 <(cut -d' ' -f1 file1 | sort) <(sed 'N;s/\n/!/' file2 | sort -k1) |
tr '!' '\n'
```

If the output needs to be sorted as in file2, you can number lines in file2 and re-sort the output on line numbers:

```
join -11 -22 -v2 <(cut -d' ' -f1 file1 | sort) <(sed 'N;s/\n/!/' file2 | nl -w1 | sort -k2) |
sort -k2 | cut -d' ' -f1,3- | tr '!' '\n'
```

[Tested on repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/DroopyLooseBaitware)

Comment: sed "$(cut -d' ' -f1 file1 | sed 's@.*@/&/{N;d}@')" file2    this solution is more than sufficient to me.  Thank you KamilCuk. I am Extremely Happy to get help from a developer. Thank you so much once again

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this with one awk, unless file1 is really really really huge :

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++; next}counter{counter--}$1 in a{counter=2}!counter' <file1> <file2>
```

Input :

file1

```
TRINITY_DN10039_c1_g1_i1        216     Brassica rapa   
TRINITY_DN10270_c0_g1_i1        233     Pan paniscus  
TRINITY_DN10323_c0_g1_i2        209     Corynebacterium aurimucosum ATCC 700975  
hello
TRINITY_DN10462_c0_g1_i1        257     Helwingia himalaica    
TRINITY_DN10596_c0_g1_i1        205     Homo sapiens   
TRINITY_DN10673_c0_g2_i2        323     Anaerococcus prevotii DSM 20548
```

file2 :

```
TRINITY_DN9856_c0_g1_i1 len=467 path=[0:0-466]
GATGCGGGCCAATATGAATGTGAGATTACTAATGAATTGGGGACTAAAAA
TRINITY_DN9842_c0_g1_i1 len=208 path=[0:0-207]
AAGTAATTTTATATCACTTGTTACATCGCAATTCGTGAGTTAAACTTAAT
TRINITY_DN9897_c0_g1_i1 len=407 path=[0:0-406]
AACTTTATTAACTTGTTGTACATATTTATTAATGCAAATACATATAGAG  
hello
world
TRINITY_DN9803_c0_g1_i1 len=795 path=[0:0-794]
AACTAAGACAAACTTCGCGGAGCAGTTAGAAAATATTACAAGAGATTTG
```

Output :

```
TRINITY_DN9856_c0_g1_i1 len=467 path=[0:0-466]
GATGCGGGCCAATATGAATGTGAGATTACTAATGAATTGGGGACTAAAAA
TRINITY_DN9842_c0_g1_i1 len=208 path=[0:0-207]
AAGTAATTTTATATCACTTGTTACATCGCAATTCGTGAGTTAAACTTAAT
TRINITY_DN9897_c0_g1_i1 len=407 path=[0:0-406]
AACTTTATTAACTTGTTGTACATATTTATTAATGCAAATACATATAGAG  
TRINITY_DN9803_c0_g1_i1 len=795 path=[0:0-794]
AACTAAGACAAACTTCGCGGAGCAGTTAGAAAATATTACAAGAGATTTG
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with process substitution like so:

```
while read -r -d '' line; do
    sed -i "/^${line}/{N;d;}" file2
done < <(awk '{printf "%s\0", $1}' file1 | sed 's|[][\\/.*^$]|\\&|g')
```

The reason for delimiting by nullbytes rather than newlines is because it's usually the best way.

Edit:
Updated to quote special characters with \ so sed won't malfunction.